# How are windows at program startup called?

Tags: terminology, gui

Often, when a program is starting it shows a modal window which has program logo, copyright information etc. For example, NetBeans shows the following window at startup:

[image]

Could anyone say how such windows are called? I've heard that there is a special term for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of window is called a ["Splash Screen"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen)

It is quickly shown before all of the program has loaded and initialized in memory.  Later versions of this support a progress bar to show loading status.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html details how to use splash screens in Java, and your example is clearly a Java example.

Note that the entire JVM / application is not loaded during the time the splash screen is presented, so there are limited means of controlling the splash screen.  If you are used to Java's Swing, or another library toolkit (graphics drawing implementation) you will see that splash screens are quite limited in their available functionality.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the type of applications.
By default, applications will not show a splash screen.

On windows os, UWP and packaged desktop applications have build in splash screen support, and that splash screen is part of the application package. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap-splashscreen

Other type of applications do not, and you have to show the splash screen yourself. Some libraries may provide splash screen support, like in the accepted answer.

Note that splash screen sometimes does more harm than good. If your app has quick startup, showing a splash screen will slow it down. It will also create an impression of sluggishness to the user, as the splash screen will interrupt the flow of things.

Comment: Are you sure this answer addresses the question?